# Apxs command showing up in Linux terminal but not Pycharm terminal

Tags: python-3.x, debian

Currently moving all of my Pycharm Projects to Linux (Debian-based distro) and had a mod_wsgi dependency in one of my projects. So I get the following error.

```
RuntimeError: The 'apxs' command appears not to be installed or is not executable. 
Please check the list of prerequisites in the documentation for this package and 
install any missing Apache httpd server packages.
```

Ok, no problem, so I install apache.

`sudo apt install apache2-dev`

Testing in the global terminal, apxs appears.

```
tony@pop-os:~$ apxs
Usage: apxs -g [-S <var>=<val>] -n <modname>
       apxs -q [-v] [-S <var>=<val>] [<query> ...]
       apxs -c [-S <var>=<val>] [-o <dsofile>] [-D <name>[=<value>]]
               [-I <incdir>] [-L <libdir>] [-l <libname>] [-Wc,<flags>]
               [-Wl,<flags>] [-p] <files> ...
       apxs -i [-S <var>=<val>] [-a] [-A] [-n <modname>] <dsofile> ...
       apxs -e [-S <var>=<val>] [-a] [-A] [-n <modname>] <dsofile> ...
```

So I restart the machine, reopen Pycharm, and try installing the requirements again.

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

Next I proceeed to type 'apxs' in the Pycharm terminal:

```
(venv) apxs
sh: apxs: command not found
```

Strange, so then I check $PATH in Pycharm:

```
(venv) echo $PATH
/home/tony/PycharmProjects/FirstDjangoProject/venv/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin
```

So, /usr/bin is where apxs is installed on the global terminal, but it isn't recognized in pycharm. Strange.

I then go take a peek in the /usr/bin dir

```
(venv) ls /usr/bin/ | grep apxs
(venv)
```

Strange. So certain files that show up in the global terminal (This applies with sudo as well) don't show up in the Pycharm terminal. Anyone know how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so here's what happened:

I am using Pop!_os and installed the Pycharm Professional flatpak from the Pop!_Shop (Pop!_os' app store). It seems installing it using snap seemed to resolve the issue. Not only that, I had to completely rebuild my venv ask it said something like "Invalid SDK". I also noticed the shell settings, along with the Python version was different (3.7 on the flatpak whereas 3.8 on the snap install).

Lesson learned. Don't always rely on the Pop!_Shop